# VueJS nested data model

Tags: nested, vue.js

I am relatively new to VueJS and am wondering how to nest/reference component's properties within others, so that the v-model binding will actually update them properly.

To illustrate, I am trying to do something like this.

Template:

```
<table>
    <tr v-for="field in myFields">
        <td class="label">{{field.label}}</td>
        <td class="user-control">
            <input v-model="field.model">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Component:

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            myFields: [
                {
                    "label": "label",
                    "model": this.propertyOne
                },
                {
                    "label": "label",
                    "model": this.propertyTwo
                }
            ],
            propertyOne: "",
            propertyTwo: ""
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, I am expecting the template to render the propertyOne and propertyTwo values (e.g. empty string) in the inputs at first, and then have those values be updated when I change them via the input, like it would normally do with the v-model.

The first works, which means that if I set to propertyOne to "Foo", it gets used as the input value initially, but subsequent changes still don't update the properties. 
I would love for this to work so that I can leverage the power of the v-for hook instead of having to write down a massive static template if I have more than 10 fields.

Answer (score 1):

When you do: `"model": this.propertyTwo` this does not make sure that all subsequent changes to `propertyTwo` will be reflected in the `model`. To Achieve this there are few options available for you.

You can use [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers), so whenever  `propertyTwo` will change you can execute a piece of code, like following:

```
watch: {
  // whenever propertyTwo changes, this function will run
  propertyTwo: function (newProp) {
    this.myFields[1].model = newProp
  }
},
```

You can also use [Computed-Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) or [method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Properties-and-Methods), which will be reactive if any associated  data changes, they will execute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem I am having is exactly this - since propertyTwo is bound to the input using the v-model directive via the "model" property of the object, changes made in the input value do not trigger the watcher on propertyTwo. I haven't tried with computed properties yet as I am pretty sure they are one-way binding so it would not solve the issue either, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @BrendanB. if you are using `propertyTwo ` with v-model, it should trigger watchers, can you add that code or create a fiddle of it?

Comment: you can see what I am trying to achieve in the initial post. I want to use the `field.model` in the v-model directive, instead of `propertyTwo`, so that I can use a v-for directive to loop over the data. If I were to use `propertyTwo` in the template, then the v-for would be useless as I would need to manually declare the properties bindings in the template, wouldn't I?

Comment: @BrendanB. So basically you  can not bind `propertyTwo` to the input using the `v-model` directive via the "model" property of the object. You may define computed property other way around, where `propertyTwo` is a computed property and the function returns `this.myFields[1].model `

Comment: Right, I'll try that and see if I can turn that thing around.